# Automate adding a new attribute field based on name

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, split-by-attribute

I frequently take in datasets of land parcels and need to split them into separate layers (Private, County, State, Federal). I have been manually creating a new attribute field and then selecting by expression with federal, state, and county fields by keyword, then multi editing to fill in my new field and finally splitting vectors.

There must be a more elegant way to do this? Or at least a way to automate these multiple steps into a script or something.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. There is certainly a way to to script this, though elegance is more in the eye of the beholder. Please make an attempt , and [Edit] this question to reflect that attempt, and whatever issue you have encountered.

Comment: Do you mean `Join attributes by location`? https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location

Comment: For a less elegant but possibly easy non-script approach if you are basing your selection on some attribute value in the datasets (such as a different number that corresponds to each government entity) you can use that number in the split by vector tool to create different layers by entity.  If you would also like the government entity name in a field you could first do a join to a table you have created and saved that has that number or numbers and the matching entity type, then run the split vector tool on the entity field of the joined layer.